# Where is usual location Jenkins installed?

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I am managing the project source configuration with SVN.

I want to automate the process of deploying the source in SVN to the development server.

Where is the usual place to install Jenkins?

1. Local PC
2. Development server
3. Another server other than 1 and 2

Development server installing

Answer (score 0):

You obviously don't want to install Jenkins in your local machine, so you options are either 2 or 3. Installing it in the development server would likely result in faster deployment and much easier setup (since you are deploying to localhost), but may not be a great idea if you see the number of deployments expanding (which would mean that whatever your deploy as well as the builds doing the deployments will have to use the same pool of resources).

Setting up Jenkins in a different server makes sense if you have multiple machines you need to deploy to, or if you simply want to keep things separate. It would be slightly more complex, and having an additional VM could be a cost overhead, so it really is up to you.